# Find and replace text by equation in Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible, in Microsoft Word 2019, to replace certain text with an equation using the *find and replace* tool?

For example, suppose I have written x_i in different places in the document and I want to put it in equation format. Could this task be done with the replace tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can absolutely be done with Microsoft Word. Firstly, type in that equation somewhere in the document using Equation tool in Word and copy it like this:

[image]

*(I have entered some `x_i` in my sample document above)*

Now press `ctrl+F`; go to `Replace` tab and Enter in **Find what:** as `x_i` and in **Replace with:** as `^c`. Press '**Replace All**' button:

[image]

You will have your text replaced by the equation. See this:

[image]

This is it. You will have your equation in place of every `x_i` in the document.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: It works, thanks! So what does exactly the ^c mean? To replace it with the copied element?

Comment: Yes. It replaces anything copied from the clipboard with preserved formatting :)